# Yii2 Gridview: Which dataProvider am I currently using?

Tags: gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I have two gridView widgets on the same page each with their own dataproviders as follows:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $userModel,
    'columns' => $columns,
]); ?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $companyModel,
    'columns' => $columns,
]); ?>
```

The columns are largely similar in both views but there are a few differences in the first three columns. What I would like to do is determine which widget is currently being compiled so that I can dynamically create the appropriate columns for that widget. For example:

```
<?php     
$columns=[];

// here is where the problem is. I would like to do something along these lines:  
if(GridView->dataProvider->id == 'userModel')
  {    
     // add custom columns    
     $columns[] = 'userName'; 
  } else {    
     // etc... 
  }

// common columns used by both grids here 
$columns[] = [
    'totalCount',
    'totalCost',
 ];
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

First create your common columns:

```
// common columns used by both grids here 
$columns = [];
$columns[] = [
    'totalCount',
    'totalCost',
 ];
```

Then create and merge the custom columns as follows:

```
 // user specific columns
$userColumns = [];
$userColumns[] = //... 
// now merge with common columns
$userColumns = array_merge($userColumns,$columns);
```

now call the appropriate column from the grid widget:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $userModel,
    'columns' => $userColumns,
]); ?>
```